# check whether a string C is an interleaving of A and B

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Given three strings A, B and C. Write a function that checks whether C is an interleaving of A and B. C is said to be interleaving A and B, if it contains all characters of A and B and order of all characters in individual strings is preserved.

For example:

- 'hotdog' is an interleaving of 'hot' and 'dog' (easy)
- 'superb' is an interleaving of 'up' and 'serb'
- 'heartache' is an interleaving of 'ear' and 'ache'
- 'chat' is an interleaving of 'hat' and 'cat'
- 'cheaters' is *not* an interleaving of 'chat' and 'seer', because while it contains all the letters from each, the letters from 'seer' do not appear in order

I find some solutions in [net](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-string-is-an-interleaving-of-two-other-given-strings-set-2/) but below is my approach can somebody tell me am i missing something or **my algo will work?** thanks.

**My Algo:**

1. Traverse through `a` and `c`. While traversal we calculate two things first: whether the char is present or not and save the index i.e. `f` where the char is found. And as soon as we find the char we should put some special char in that place, so that we will not consider this char further.
2. For the next char in `a` search in the `c` from the index where you have found the previous char i.e. `f`. if we don't find than return.
3. Same you do for `b` as well.
4. If after doing the above step if we find `false` than repeat for first `b` than `a` and return the result.

e.g.

```
a = xxy, b = xxz and c = xxzxxxy
```

> start with a:
>
> 1. for x in a,  c = 0xzxxxy (i am putting 0 as special char)
> 2. for x in a, start from the index 0 onwards(because we have found the previous char at 0)c = 00zxxxy.
> 3. for y in a, c = 00zxxx0
> 4. for x in b, c = 00z0xx0
> 5. for x in b, c = 00z00x0
> 6. for z in b, we could not find z after the index 4 which was the index where we found the previous char for b.
>
> as starting with **`a`** returns false so we will start with **b** now.
>
> So start with b:
>
> 1. for x in b, c = 0xzxxxy
> 2. for x in b, c = 00zxxxy
> 3. for z in b, c = 000xxxy
> 4. for x in a, c = 0000xxy
> 5. for x in a, c = 00000xy
> 6. for y in a, c = 00000x0

hence true i.e.c is the interleaved string of a and b.

Comment: I suspect this is a more complex problem than it sounds at first, since you can easily end up going down the wrong path and having to backtrack.

Comment: Can this take as long as it wants? Or do you have to fulfil a complexity requirement?

Comment: @Cruncher the solution above is O(N^2). you can have your say on the algo above or your own also.

Comment: @Trying: Why did you remove the link? I think the DP solution is among the best solutions you can find.

Comment: @nhahtdh you want me to restore it? i thought of trying solution here afresh.

Comment: Classical DP problem. `O(n^2)` is pretty standard, I don't believe you can do any better in the worst case

Comment: @Trying: It saves everyone time regarding to what you have researched. And I really doubt that it is possible to do better.

Comment: @nhahtdh command executed, link restored :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution represents a [*greedy algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) with a slight modification, because it counts a character in `C` as belonging to `A` on the first pass (or to `B` on the second pass) as soon as it finds a match. This will break for the following strings:

```
A = xxyxxy
B = xxzxxz
C = xxzxxyxxyxxz
```

The firs pass that counts a matching character as a member of `A` will turn `C` into

```
00zxx0000xxz
```

The second pass that counts a matching character as a member of `B` will turn `C` into

```
00000yxxyxx0
```

Here is a simple Java implementation of a [memoized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) solution:

```
private static boolean checkOverlap(String a, String b, String c) {
    Boolean[][][] memoize = new Boolean[a.length()+1][b.length()+1][c.length()+1];
    return checkOverlap(a, b, c, 0, 0, 0, memoize);
}
private static boolean checkOverlap(
    String a
,   String b
,   String c
,   int pa
,   int pb
,   int pc
,   Boolean[][][] memoize
) {
    Boolean res = memoize[pa][pb][pc];
    if (res != null) {
        return (boolean)res;
    }
    if (pa == a.length() && pb == b.length() && pc == c.length()) {
        res = true;
    } else if (pc == c.length()) {
        res = false;
    } else {
        res = false;
        if (pa != a.length() && c.charAt(pc) == a.charAt(pa) && checkOverlap(a, b, c, pa+1, pb, pc+1, memoize)) {
            res = true;
        } else if (pb != b.length() && c.charAt(pc) == b.charAt(pb) && checkOverlap(a, b, c, pa, pb+1, pc+1, memoize)) {
            res = true;
        }
    }
    return (memoize[pa][pb][pc] = res);
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/LGldVW)

Comment: could you please suggest one, probably efficient. Thanks.

Comment: @Trying The DP-based solution (the second one) [from the site that you referenced before the edit](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-string-is-an-interleaving-of-two-other-given-strings-set-2/) is very efficient. You could also convert the first solution (the recursive one) to an efficient one by applying [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: i followed the link but i am not able to find the overlapping sub problems in the recursive approach so that i can use memorization. Please help me in finding the subproblems at-least  and from that i can take off i feel. Thanks.

Comment: @Trying I added a Java implementation of the memoized recursive solution from your link - take a look.

Comment: if i had got powers to give you more points than +1 and accepting the answer, i would have used that.

Comment: can we get the same result wit 2D array for memoize. just a and b location.

Comment: @Trying I think [we can](http://ideone.com/ZcjgJe), but I'm having hard time proving it.

Comment: i think value for `pc=pa+pb`. Because if value at `pc` is not equal to `pa` or `pb` than it just returns false simply. So `pc` will always be sum of `pa`, `pb`. Hence if we can memoize for `pa`, `pb` then we don't need `pc`. if `pc` could move independently then we would save `pc` but this is not the case. Your comment on this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd check that the length of A and the length of B summed equal the length of C.

Next, check if the first character of A is equal to the first character of C.

If not, check if the first character of B is equal to the first character of C.

Check the other characters starting with either A or B, depending on which of the two conditions above was true.

Here's a method that will do the test:

```
public boolean isInterleaved(String a, String b, String c) {
    int aIndex = 0;
    int bIndex = 0;
    int cIndex = 0;
    while (cIndex < c.length()) {
        if (aIndex < a.length()) {
            if (a.charAt(aIndex) != c.charAt(cIndex)) { return false; }
            cIndex++;
            aIndex++;
        }
        if (bIndex < b.length()) { 
            if (b.charAt(bIndex) != c.charAt(cIndex)) { return false; }
            cIndex++;
            bIndex++;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You would call this method at most twice.  The calls would be either

```
if (isInterleaved(a, b, c))
```

or

```
if (isInterleaved(b, a, c))
```

If the first character of A and the first character of B are equal, check the other characters starting with the A or B string you didn't start with in the previous step.

This way, you save the complicated testing for the strings that can possibly satisfy the conditions.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I can do all the above optimization but can you please tell me whether my approach above will give me correct result or not? Thanks.

Comment: @Trying: I'd just do a simple loop over the C characters.  See my edited answer.

Comment: I got index out of bounds with: `isInterleaved("xxxy", "xx", "xxxxxy")`, and it returns true for `isInterleaved("x", "xx", "x")`

Comment: @Trying: I forgot that the A and B strings could be different lengths.  See my edited answer.  You're also supposed to be doing the other tests I outlined before you call this method.

Comment: check for:   String A = "xxyxxy";
        String B = "xxzxxz";
        String C = "xxzxxyxxyxxz"; answer should be true but your code will return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
def isinterleave(a, b, c):
   la = len(a)
   lb = len(b)
   lc = len(c)
   if la + lb != lc: return False
   if la == lb == lc == 0: return True
   if (la > 0 and lb >0 and a[0] == b[0] == c[0]):
     return isinterleave(a[1:], b, c[1:]) or isinterleave(a, b[1:], c[1:])
   if (la > 0 and a[0] == c[0]):
     return isinterleave(a[1:], b, c[1:])
   if (lb > 0 and b[0] == c[0]):
     return isinterleave(a, b[1:], c[1:])
   return False
```